# customizing logo in mkdocs and material

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I have a documentation website, and I'm trying to customize the logo size. However, I'm not sure how to access the HTML tags using the [customization](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/customization/) suggestions provided. It seems that I can embed some CSS code, but for example, how can I identify the HTML tags that I want to customize, given that the index page is in a markdown file?

Thank you in advance.